# A Debian 10 UEFI disk and another Debian 10 MBR disk are on the same computer with NO dual-boot. Can I then select any disk in the BIOS to boot on it?

Tags: debian, boot, uefi, mbr

A reseller is creating a new computer for me. It will have an *UEFI Debian 10* on it.

He will also add an old *MBR Debian 10* disk on it, I will provide to him.
This disk is only here to ensure that I'm not missing anything when I will perform re-installations, for a few weeks, and I don't plan to link the "old" disk to the new *Debian 10* GRUB. I won't attempt to do a dual boot.

I want to know, having :

- an UEFI disk, **A**
- a MBR disk, **B**

Will I be able to boot my computer by changing  only the booting disk **A** or **B** in the BIOS ?

Comment: You should. You may need to change UEFI settings. Some that even say UEFI or BIOS only boot in one mode or the other Or may need UEFI only or CSM/BIOS/Legacy boot mode. And UEFI Secure Boot must be off to boot an old MBR configured drive. Once you start booting in one mode or other, you cannot switch. Or grub can only dual boot installs in same boot mode.

Comment: Will "_UEFI secure boot off_" still allow the UEFI disk to start its Debian ?

Comment: Yes. Even systems installed with Secure Boot on, normally boot with Secure Boot off. Some proprietary drivers like video or wireless are easier to install with Secure boot off. If installed with Secure boot off, you may not have the kernels, drivers & grub that are signed for Secure Boot, not sure with Debian if two versions or not.

Comment: @oldfred this story of signed drivers is worrying me : when I will "discard" (converting to a data disk) my old Debian MBR disk, will I be allowed to switch my BIOS to UEFI Secure Boot on again (if, for weeks long, it updated itself with unsigned drivers) ?

Comment: You might also find this set of pages helpful (I did back in 2012 when implementing UEFI support in ALT Linux): http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Comment: The signed drivers would be in your install, you would not install from another install. The boot of an UEFI install is totally separate from a BIOS boot. I normally keep UEFI Secure Boot off, but may sometime in future have to turn it on, so I just try to stay up to date.  BIOS boot cannot update any BIOS settings. UEFI does allow some setting to be changed by an operating system or be updated, depending on brand/model system.